# Can you optimize heap allocations?

Tags: c++

I need to return a pointer in a function but initializing a variable on the stack will not work because the pointer will be deleted once the function ends. So now I have to use a heap. The problem is this function could be used to initialize potentially hundreds of objects. Can you optimize heap allocations or avoid allocating on the heap entirely?

I have to do this because I want this to work with an array. If I try and pass in a pointer to an index of the array, I believe it will create a temporary object pointer and will be deleted at the end of the function.

So my solution was to create an array of object pointers but if I return a regular object I cant cast it to an array as the function is an rvalue.

Code Example:

```
Obj* createObj(params)
{
    // do func stuff

    Obj* obj;

    // init obj

    return obj;
}
```

Some where else in the project.

```
std::array<Obj*, 100> objs;

Scene scene;

void Start()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++)
  {
     objs[i] = createObj(params);
     // This pointer will be deleted after the function call
     // casing the pointer in the array to be pointing to deleted memory!
     scene.add(objs[i]);
  }
}

void update()
{
   draw(scene); // the scene needs a pointer to the array as it need to know if any objs have changed
}
```

Comment: Do you absolutely HAVE to return a pointer? [Copy Elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) wants to be your friend.

Comment: To get answers that address your specific case, we need to know your specific case. Without specifics the best we can do is give general advice. And that general advice is don't use the pointer unless you're forced to use the pointer.

Comment: "*the pointer will be deleted once the function ends*" Do you mean with the actual `delete`? Because if it's using `delete` (or `free` or any other non-replacable memory allocator), there's not much you can do.

Comment: *"Can you optimize heap allocations*" - you can always write your own allocator, though given the code sample I'd first try to rethink the design (e.g.: using an `std::vector<Obj>` instead of an array of pointers)

Comment: Unrelated: From this quick example, it looks like `obj` might be unnecessary. Can you not add the created object directly to `scene`?

Comment: Does `scene.add()` have to take a pointer? It's not that pointers are evil, but they are certainly making your life harder here.

Comment: What does the *"This pointer will be deleted after the function call"*? Is it your code, or code you can't change?

Comment: Why isn't `createObj` a constructor in `Obj` instead?

Comment: Wondered the same, but I have no clue what is in `// do func stuff`. Might not be stuff you want in `Obj`.

Comment: @user4581301 Perhaps, but the `// init obj` part should probably go into the constructor.

Comment: That's 100% agreement.